# Etale iff Completions are Isomorphic

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, schemes, formal-completions

I have a question aboutthe proof of proposition 4.3.26 from Liu's "Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves":

Let $Y$ be a locally Noetherian scheme and $f:X \to Y$ a morphism of finite type. Fix a point $x$ and denote $y=f(x)$. Assume that $O_{X,x}/m_x=k(x)=k(y)=O_{Y,y}/m_y$ coincide.

The local ring morphism on stalks $f_x:O_{Y,y} \to O_{X,x}$ induces a morphism of completions

$$\widehat{f}_x:\widehat{O}_{Y,y} \to \widehat{O}_{X,x}$$

where the completions are induced wrt to corresponding maximal ideals $m_x$ and $m_y$.

The proposition says that $f$ is etale in $x$ if and only if $\widehat{f}_x:\widehat{O}_{Y,y} \to \widehat{O}_{X,x}$ is an isomorphism.

The "$\Rightarrow$" I understand. Regarding the "$\Leftarrow$" I don't understand the argument.

Liu refers to Theorem 1.3.16 and Exercise 1.2.18.

Recall etale means ***flat and unramified***.

Exercise 1.2.18 solves the flatness of $f_x$: It says that if $B \to E$ is faithful flat then $A \to B$ is flat if and only if $A \to E$ is flat. Taking for $A \to B$ the morphism $f_x$ and for $E$ the completion we are done since completions of local rings are faithful flat.

Recall unramified means that $k(y) \to k(x)$ is separable and $m_yO_{X,x}=m_x$.

QUESTION:
By assumption $k(y) = k(x)$ so the first one is ok but what about $m_yO_{X,x}=m_x$?

My considerations:Since $\widehat{f}_x$ is an iso we deduce that

1. $\widehat{m_x} = \widehat{m_y}\widehat{O}_{X,x}$ as completions
2. $O_{Y,y}/m_y \cong \widehat{O}_{Y,y}/\widehat{m_y} \to  \widehat{O}_{X,x}/\widehat{m_x} \cong O_{X,x}/m_x$ are surjective.
3. for every $k$ there exist a $d_k$ with $ g(m_y)^{d_k} \subset m_x ^k$ and vice versa (so same topology)

But I don't see how to conclude that $m_yO_{X,x}=m_x$.

Comment: Please check your notation. If $y=f(x)$, the map between local rings goes the other way.

Comment: Ups, thank you for remark!

Comment: This is an easy consequence of the fact that $m_y\mathcal{O}_{Y,y}^\wedge=m_y^\wedge$. From here, $m_y\mathcal{O}_{X,x}^\wedge=m_y\mathcal{O}_{X,x}\mathcal{O}_{X,x}^\wedge=m_x\mathcal{O}_{X,x}^\wedge$ and you're done.

Comment: @KReiser:Why are we here done? $m_y\mathcal{O}_{X,x}^\wedge=m_x\mathcal{O}_{X,x}^\wedge$ is indeed a consequence of 1) (see above) and $\widehat{M}=M \otimes \widehat{A}$ for all $A$ modules $M$. If $M=I$ is an ideal of $A$ then by ***flatness*** of completion we also have $I \otimes \widehat{A}= I\widehat{A}$ (this was your argument,right? Now why can we already conclude $m_yO_{X,x}=m_x$ from $m_y\mathcal{O}_{X,x}^\wedge=m_x\mathcal{O}_{X,x}^\wedge$? What is the main ingredient?

Comment: The ***faithful flatness*** (since this is a completion of a local ring) or does here only flatness suffice and your argument is more general in the sense that the conclusion work for general completions of rings?

Comment: Indeed, if we use faithful flatness (so sequence of $A$-modules $0 \to N_1 \to N_2 \to N_3 \to 0$ exact if and only if $0 \to N_1 \otimes \widehat{A} \to N_2 \otimes \widehat{A} \to N_3 \otimes \widehat{A} \to 0$ exact) then we have two sequences $0 \to m_x \to O_{X,x} \to k(x) \to 0$ and $0 \to m_y O_{X,x} \to O_{X,x} \to k(x) \to 0$ where the first one is exact by definition, the second one at first glance not, but after tensoring with completion these both coinside and are therefore exact.

Comment: By faithful flatness $0 \to m_y O_{X,x} \to O_{X,x} \to k(x) \to 0$ was therefore also exact and by uniqueness of kernel we are done. Is this the argument you have in mind which allows to conclude $m_yO_{X,x}=m_x$ from $m_y\mathcal{O}_{X,x}^\wedge=m_x\mathcal{O}_{X,x}^\wedge$ or do you mean a more "simple" one?